# Scala Lift - Load model within Comet actor

Tags: scala, comet, lift

I have the following comet actor (shortened for readability):

```
class Relay_Comet extends CometActor with CometListener {


    def render = {


         var user_model = User.findAll(

             ("room" -> "test")

         )


         OnLoad(JsRaw(
         """

             var user = []                

         """
         ).cmd)


    }


}
```

I'm trying to load all users from the db when the actor receives a new message, this has to be done every time it recieves a message as the user records need to be up to date, however I'm getting the following error at runtime:

```
overloaded method value findAll with alternatives:
[error]   (ids: List[org.bson.types.ObjectId])List[code.model.User] <and>
[error]   (qry: net.liftweb.json.JsonAST.JObject,opts: net.liftweb.mongodb.FindOption*)List[code.model.User] <and>
[error]   (qry: com.mongodb.DBObject,opts: net.liftweb.mongodb.FindOption*)List[code.model.User] <and>
[error]   => List[code.model.User]
[error]  cannot be applied to (Relay_Comet.this.TheStrBindParam)
[error]                 var user_model = User.findAll(
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to import BsonDSL._